# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, api, rest, flask

Soy nuevo haciendo en las REST API en general, estoy iniciando con Flask, y siguiendo instrucciones desde un libro logré llegar a cierto punto y pude hacer mi primer script, pero me ha saltado un error recurrente, que no he podido resolver...
Nota: Estoy usando XAMPP.

Primero cree una base de datos y una tabla:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE `tttcontrol` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci */;

use tttcontrol;

--
-- Table structure for table `sim`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sim`;
CREATE TABLE `sim`(
  `telephone` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `account` varchar(15)  COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `father_account` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `iccid` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `package` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status`  tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `cancellation_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`telephone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish_ci;
```

Después introduje tres filas de datos...

```sql
INSERT INTO sim (`telephone`,`account`,`father_account`,`iccid`,`package`,`status`,`cancellation_date`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`created_by`,`updated_by`,`deleted_by`)
VALUES ('3121234567', '001','000','0101','P1','1',now(),now(),now(),now(),'008','008','008');
INSERT INTO sim (`telephone`,`account`,`father_account`,`iccid`,`package`,`status`,`cancellation_date`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`created_by`,`updated_by`,`deleted_by`)
VALUES ('9876543210', '002','000','0102','P1','1',now(),now(),now(),now(),'005','005','005');
INSERT INTO sim (`telephone`,`account`,`father_account`,`iccid`,`package`,`status`,`cancellation_date`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`created_by`,`updated_by`,`deleted_by`)
VALUES ('0123456789', '003','000','0103','P1','1',now(),now(),now(),now(),'001','001','001');
```

Finalmente, está el cripst para las acciones en dicha BD...

```py
from flask import Flask, json, jsonify, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()

api = Api(app)

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'x'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'x'

mysql.init_app(app)

class SimList(Resource):
  def get(self):
    try:
      conn = mysql.connect()
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM sim""")
      rows = cursor.fetchall()
      return jsonify(rows)
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
    finally:
      cursor.close()
      conn.close()

  def post(self):
    try:
      conn = mysql.connect()
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      _telephone = request.form['telephone'] 
      _account = request.form['account']
      _father_account = request.form['father_account']
      _iccid = request.form['iccid']
      _package = request.form['package']
      _status = request.form['status']
      _cancellation_date = request.form['cancellation_date']
      _created_at = request.form['created_at']
      _updated_at = request.form['updated_at']
      _deleted_at = request.form['deleted_at']
      _created_by = request.form['created_by']
      _updated_by = request.form['updated_by']
      _deleted_by = request.form['deleted_by']
      insert_sim_cmd = """INSERT INTO sim(telephone, account, father_account, iccid, package, status, cancellation_date, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, created_by, updated_by, deleted_by)"""
      cursor.execute(insert_sim_cmd,(_telephone, _account, _father_account, _iccid, _package, _status, _cancellation_date, _created_at, _updated_at, _deleted_at, _created_by, _updated_by, _deleted_by))
      conn.commit()
      response = jsonify(message = 'Sim added successfully!')
      # response.data = cursor.lastrowid
      response.status_code = 200
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      response = jsonify('Failed to add sim!')
      response.status_code = 400
    finally:
      cursor.close()
      conn.close()
      return(response)

class Sim(Resource):
  def get(self, sim_telephone):
    try:
      conn = mysql.connect()
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sim WHERE telephone=%s', sim_telephone)
      rows = cursor.fetchall()
      return jsonify(rows)
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
    finally:
      cursor.close()
      conn.close()

  def put(sefl, sim_telephone):
    try:
      conn = mysql.connect()
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      _telephone = request.form['telephone']
      _account = request.form['account']
      _father_account = request.form['father_account']
      _iccid = request.form['iccid']
      _package = request.form['package']
      _status = request.form['status']
      _cancellation_date = request.form['cancellation_date']
      _created_at = request.form['created_at']
      _updated_at = request.form['updated_at']
      _deleted_at = request.form['deleted_at']
      _created_by = request.form['created_by']
      _updated_by = request.form['updated_by']
      _deleted_by = request.form['deleted_by']
      update_sim_cmd = """UPDATE sim SET account=%s, father_account=%s, iccid=%s, package=%s, status=%s, cancellation_date=%s, created_at=%s, updated_at=%s, deleted_at=%s, created_by=%s, updated_by=%s, deleted_by=%s where sim_telephone=%s"""
      cursor.execute(update_sim_cmd,(_account, _father_account, _iccid, _package, _status, _cancellation_date, _created_at, _updated_at, _deleted_at, _created_by, _updated_by, _deleted_by, sim_telephone))
      conn.commit()
      response = jsonify('Sim updated successfully!')
      response.status_code = 200
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      response = jsonify('Failed to update sim')
      response.status_code = 400
    finally:
      cursor.close()
      conn.close()
      return(response)

  def delete(self, sim_telephone):
    try:
      conn = mysql.connect()
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('DELETE FROM sim WHERE telephone=%s', sim_telephone)
      conn.commit()
      response = jsonify('Sim deleted succesfully!')
      response.status_code = 200
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      response = jsonify('Failed to delete sim!')
      response.status_code = 400
    finally:
      cursor.close()
      conn.close()
      return(response)

api.add_resource(SimList, '/sims', endpoint='sims')
api.add_resource(Sim, '/sim/<int:sim_telephone>', endpoint='sim')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Cuando corro el script e intenta conectarse a http://127.0.0.1:5000/sims ohttp://127.0.0.1:5000/sim/int:sim_telephone salta el siguiente error...

```
File "C:\GitHub\restful_api_mysql_crud\app.py", line 35, in get
cursor.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment
```

En este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493631/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-cursor-referenced-before-assignment encontré la misma pregunta, pero no entendí cómo podría aplicar a mi caso la respuesta.

Apreciaré mucho toda la ayuda, muchas gracias por adelantado!

Comment: hay un problema en la conexión y por eso no se crea el cursor, debido a que el cursor no se creo, la variable `cursor` no esta,por que esa linea todavia no se ha ejecutado

Comment: Hola @elweoncalvo, sí me he percatado de ello, después de probar algunas soluciones con la declaración del cursor; al parecer estoy usando mal las credenciales para conectar a la base de datos